# Kendo Column chart not showing any column,after publishing website on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Im getting crazy over this issue,on my browser and my computer I can see the chart and and its columns ,but after publishing on IIS ,data is there but ,empty chart!,its not a complicated thing but i am wondering why this happen,im sending data as a JSON,i have also checked there if all my javascript file has been copied in the IIS ,all is ok,here is my controller:

```
 List<FaultStatErrorIdViewModel> erro_id = new List<FaultStatErrorIdViewModel>();
      foreach (DataRow dr in dt_error.Rows)
      {

          FaultStatErrorIdViewModel _error = new FaultStatErrorIdViewModel();
          _error.cur_year = dr["cur_year"].ToString();
          _error.error_dur = dr["error_duration_this_year"].ToString();
          _error.m_error_id = dr["m_error_id"].ToString();
           erro_id.Add(_error);
       }
return Json(erro_id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Here is my chart:

```
         $.ajax({

                                  dataType: "json",
                                  type: "POST",
                                  url: "@Url.Action("faultStatErrorId","Ranking")",
                                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                  data: JSON.stringify({ "regionalManager": tmpString,"error_name":itemname, "dtFrom": dtFrom, "dtTo": dtTo }),
                                  success: function (rslt) {                                                                       
                                      $("#error_id_Chart").kendoChart({
                                          dataSource: {
                                              data: rslt
                                          },

                                          title: {
                                              text: "Main-Group:" + itemname,
                                              position: "bottom",

                                          },

                                          chartArea: {
                                              background: "#fcfcfc",
                                              width: 700,

                                          },
                                          series: [{
                                              //  data: finaldata,
                                              type: "column",
                                              name: "DURATION",
                                              color: "blue",
                                              field: "error_dur",
                                              categoryField: "m_error_id",
                                          }],

                                          legend: {

                                              visible: false

                                          },
                                          valueAxes: {
                                              name: "Duration",
                                              title: { text: "Duration (Hrs)" },
                                              majorGridLines: {

                                                  visible: false


                                              },
                                              line: {



                                                  visible: true
                                              },


                                          },

                                          tooltip: {
                                              visible: true,

                                              // majorUnit:10,
                                              template: " #= value #"
                                          },

                                      });



                                }
                                   });
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier no,not in the network nor console,

Comment: so if you are not seeing any errors in the console what is being returned from the request? I am assuming this is working locally for you? Have you tried to call your chart end point manually to see what is being returned? Is this accessing a database of some description and if so is there data actually being returned back?

Comment: @DavidShorthose works locally right,when I put debugger ,and publish it, I can see data in the server browser also,for sure the data is there

Comment: so if you called `yourwebsite/Ranking/faultStatErrorId` using something like fiddler or postman with the data you need to send across what are you seeing come back? This sounds like a potential deployment issue rather than a code issue and without seeing a working example i.e. somewhere to go to to test it,  it is going to be difficult to find out what the route cause of your issue is. Are you able to post the results from trying to hit your chart endpoint to see what is being returned. Also what browser are you using?

Comment: @DavidShorthose IE11,i try to write in fiddle